# how can i click button on webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

```
<div class="Buttons">
  <button class="Button SemiRound Blue" id="SummonerRefreshButton" onclick="$.OP.GG.summoner.renewBtn.start(this, '1071306');" style="position: relative;">Yenile</button>
  <button class="Button SemiRound White" id="SpectateButton" onclick="$.OP.GG.summoner.openSpectator('gamesistemcom', '#ExtraView')">Live Game</button>
  <button class="Button SemiRound White" onclick="$.OP.GG.summoner.openMMR('gamesistemcom', '#ExtraView')">MMR'ı Kontrol Et</button>
  <button class="Button SemiRound White" onclick="$.OP.GG.summoner.openLpHistoryGraph('gamesistemcom', '#ExtraView');">Tier Graph</button>
```

```
string mmrDocument = "";
    private void Wb2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        wb2.Document.GetElementById("buttonID").InvokeMember("click");
        mmrDocument = wb2.DocumentText;
    }
```

How can i click "MMR'ı Kontrol Et" button ? (This doesn't have an ID value)

Comment: In your case maybe this: `Wb2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button").Where(button => button.GetAttribute("onclick").Equals("$.OP.GG.summoner.openMMR('gamesistemcom', '#ExtraView')")).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Where method not found

Comment: Try add `using System.Linq`